# MySQL with docker-compose: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.22.0.1' every ~24h

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a Java application which uses docker-compose. I have MySQL database connected by docker-compose.

When I run my application on docker `CMD: docker-compose up --build` *everything works great*! But after ~24h I get **exception as below**. Can you suggest me please where may be the problem?

```
docker_application          | com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.22.0.1' (using password: YES)
docker_application          |  at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor98.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
docker_application          |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
docker_application          |  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:816) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:741) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:709) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:540) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1452) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:849) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:830) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
docker_application          |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar!/:8.0.16]
```

**docker-compose:**

```
  dictionary_app_prod_mysql:
    container_name: dictionary_app_prod_mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "mysql-log:/var/log/mysql"
      - "mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "general"
      MYSQL_USER: "root"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://dictionary_app_prod_mysql:3306/general?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
```

Comment: `Access denied for user 'root'@'172.22.0.1' (using password: YES)` is pretty clear. If this works for while and suddenly  stops with this message, you need to find out why the permissions have changed on your db or why the credentials you use on your app have changed without you knowing.

Comment: @Zeitounator it works normally for a few hours. DB is available. But after some time I just see `Access denied for user 'root'@'172.22.0.1' (using password: YES)` in application's logs and db's logs. And nothing more. 0 additional messages. How can I verify it?

Comment: What else is accessing this db instance ? A user password does not change on its own. Note that your are portmapping to localhost. So any mysql client app on your host could connect.